How to create an AWS cognito user pool with username as the only sign-in identifier
In my application I dont want to store user emails. So previously I have used only the username as the sign-in identifier in Cognito. But after November 2024 release, Its asking to set email or phone no as required attributes for sign up.
This has an impact on the existing application's behavior. Is there anyway to skip adding the extra attributes for sign up and continue as before.


Still we can create the user pool only with username as the sign up attributes from cloudformation templates. But Im not sure this will get changed in a future release.
